# Is there any assignment operator overloading "alternatives"? Like "binary" analog of conversion operators (that takes both in account)?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, operators, instance, conversion-operator

I **certainly** want to assign value **directly** to my class instance (implicitly to one of its properties), but besides overloading assignment operator (which is forbidden?), I found only conversion operator, which is kind of what I need, but it doesn't account the "assignee" instance in any way (instead it creates and assigns new object, with all that it implies).

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool b = true;

    public float f = 1f;
    public float f2 = 10f;

    public float value 
    {
        get => b? f : f2; 
        set => b? f : f2;
    }

    public Foo(bool useFirstFloat, float f)
    {
        this.b = first;
        this.value = f;
    }

    public static implicit operator float(Foo foo) => foo.f;
    public static implicit operator Foo(float f) => new Foo(true, f); //bool is always "overwritten"

    public float this[bool useInstance] //For ugly workaround example
    {
        get => value; 
        set => useInstance? value : new Foo(false, value); //now with false
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(false, 100f); //bool must stay "false" after assignment
float f = 5f;
void SomeFunc()
{
    foo.value = f; //I want this, but not this way!
    foo = f; //Instead I want this to be the same thing as "foo.value = f" (not "foo = new Foo(b, f)"!)
    foo[true] = f; //Like this but without index parameter
    foo[false] = f; //Not this, again!
}
```

So in ideal I need something like this:

```
public static Foo operator =(Foo foo, float f) //Why is this so forbidden?
{
    foo.value = f;
    return foo;
}
```

Is there any way to do so? Any thoughts on possibility of this in C#?

Comment: This is similar to how VB6 had the `Set` and `Let` keywords for assignments. You had to use `Set` to assign an object instance to the variable, whereas `Let` would assign the default property. This does not exist in VB.NET or C#.

Comment: If you want to overload the assignment operators, use C++. It's not part of C# and it probably never will be. As for the "why", read everything that Eric Lippert has ever written on C# language design and you'll start to understand.

Comment: @madreflection I don't actually need to overload assignment operator, more like to have the way to access the left side of expression from inside conversion operator.

Comment: That's not possible. Conversion operators have no concept of how they fit into the larger expression. Simply put, you need to go about it another way.

Comment: @madreflection and that's the question: is there another way with C# (and if so, what is it)?

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're trying to do something using a C++ idiom that you can't do in C#. Reframe the question in terms of what kinds of rules you're trying to enforce with `Foo`. Someone should be able to explain how to idiomatically do that in C#.

Comment: @madreflection the question is simple: using C#, I want make "foo = 1f" to mean "foo.value = 1f", not "foo = new Foo(1f)", like with conversion. And I'm just repeating myself here, meanwhile C++ looks the only solution (even though out of the question scope).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: **NO** (use C++). But there's hack to implement similar behaviour (unsafe)!

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool b = true;

    public float f = 1f;
    public float f2 = 10f;

    public static Foo current;

    public float value 
    {
        get
        {
            current = this;
            return b? f : f2; 
        }
        set
        {
            current = this;
            if (b) f = value; else f2 = value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator float(Foo foo) => foo.f;
    public static implicit operator Foo(float f)
    {
        current.value = f;
        return current;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, at this moment it's not possible in C# by default, and actually forbidden. But no matter what the dogma dicts, there's sudden lack of functional that appears like a snag while everything is fine, so I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2441), for anybody can see what it leds to.

UPD: Issue was merged with some barelated stuff, but [there](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2773) is some discussion.